# How to access a table I inserted manually into Drupal 7 db

Tags: database, theming

I just inserted a new table into the Drupal db called `mini_table` with my own custom data using only phpmysql. How do I access this table's data for use in my *.tpl.php files?

**EDIT:** No cause for alarm. All my code is in `template.php` and not in any **.tpl.php* file. Just wanted to clarify that.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't do  a query from a .tpl.php or include any php logic there. If you have to do it in the theme (this would be better in a small custom module), do it in the template.php in a preprocess function (node or page preprocess, depending on what template you want your variable available).

So you do your query in the template.php file and then through a preprocess function send the variable to your .tpl.php files.

I also don't recommend writing MySQL queries in Drupal, you should use the Drupal API for this. Drupal has a [database abstraction layer](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/group/database/7) that gives you lots of handy function you can use.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that my current code is written in template.php. Will check out that link and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

As @ipwa said, you shouldn't perform queries in template files.

If you'd want to access custom data in Drupal 7 I suggest you use the [Entity API](http://drupal.org/node/1261744). It defines a custom entity with it's own schema (table) in the database.